# Slack RTM with python-rtmbot: making short-links work

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I'm developing a plugin for [python-rtmbot](https://github.com/slackhq/python-rtmbot) and I'm trying to output short-links from that plugin, like this:
`<http://google.com|test>`. My goal is to display this in Slack: [test](http://google.com) -  a clickable link without displaying the full URL.

However, my Slack bot would just display the raw text `<http://google.com|test>`. I modified the function called **output()** in file **rtmbot.py**:

```
def output(self):
    for plugin in self.bot_plugins:
        limiter = False
        for output in plugin.do_output():
            channel = self.slack_client.server.channels.find(output[0])
            if channel != None and output[1] != None:
                if limiter == True:
                    time.sleep(.1)
                    limiter = False
                message = output[1].encode('ascii','ignore') + "<http://google.com|test>"
                #channel.send_message("{}".format(message))
                self.slack_client.api_call('chat.postMessage', channel=output[0], text=message, as_user=True)
                limiter = True
```

Instead of using **channel.send_message()**, I switched to using **self.slack_client.api_call()**, which is an instance of *SlackClient* from the *slackclient* package. The link is displayed correctly now, but it takes longer to display (output is slower).

Is there a way to still use *channel.send_message()* with short-links capability? Any other ideas/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The RTM API only supports posting simple messages formatted using our [default message formatting mode](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting).

To post a more complex message you can call the chat.postMessage Web API method as you've done through the python slackclient lib. I dont think there is any better solution as of now.